# ng-class multiple condition in on statement

Tags: angularjs

I need to check if two things is true to decide the class. I have been trying to find a solution for this because i believe this should be a pretty common problem. Maybe i'm just searching for the wrong things.

I want to have two conditions in one statement, if that is what it is called?

I've tried similar things to this:

```
   ng-class="{'in-behalf-of-background-color' : parameters.Username == quote.InBehalfOf } ,{'not-in-behalf-of-background-color' : ((parameters.Username != quote.InBehalfOf) && (quote.InBehalfOf != 'null'))}"
```

As you can see i want to check parameters.Username != quote.InBehalfOf and also if quote.InBehalfOf != null in the same condition. Is this possible?

Comment: that should be working, right?

Comment: yeah i thought so to but it doesn't :(

Comment: well it is nice to move such logic to controller as view logic is hard to debug. make a single variable or function to get boolean for applying that class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this code;

You want multiple condition then define one object and define conditions with key value pair `{key1:value1, key2: value2}`

```
ng-class="{'in-behalf-of-background-color' : parameters.Username == quote.InBehalfOf, 'not-in-behalf-of-background-color' : ((parameters.Username != quote.InBehalfOf) && (quote.InBehalfOf)) }"
```

Comment: this makes all of them get the class : not-in-behalf-of-background-color

Comment: Maybe, you wrong used last condition try this code`((parameters.Username != quote.InBehalfOf) && (quote.InBehalfOf))` instead of `((parameters.Username != quote.InBehalfOf) && (quote.InBehalfOf != 'null'))`

Answer (score 1):

The thing you are missing is, for multiple classes in `ng-class` you don't need to create another `{..}`. You can specify multiple just by seperating them with a comma `,`. So, the following should work,

```
ng-class="{'in-behalf-of-background-color' : parameters.Username == quote.InBehalfOf, 
    'not-in-behalf-of-background-color' : (parameters.Username != quote.InBehalfOf) && (quote.InBehalfOf != 'null')}"
```

Comment: this makes all of them get the class : not-in-behalf-of-background-color :(

Comment: @DanielGustafsson should be an issue with what you have in conditions. Syntactically, `ng-class` is written correctly here

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 ng-class="{'in-behalf-of-background-color' : parameters.Username === quote.InBehalfOf , 'not-in-behalf-of-background-color' : ((parameters.Username !== quote.InBehalfOf) && (quote.InBehalfOf !== 'null'))}"
```

refer [angular ng-class doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClassOdd)